Replit debugger- not working for me- no comments
enter image description hereenter image description hereI am trying to practice debugging and for the life of me i cant get the comments to come up under the debugger. i have added a break point and pressed run in the debugger and it remains blank. in the console it comes up with just the result Blastoff! which is what i am expecting for now with the current code.
IF anyone could help me that would be great and appreciated. I dont know if i am doing something wrong or if its an issue with the settings. As i meant to use the debugger to find the issues but no variables or anything is coming up.
Thanks team.
Trying to debug and expecting comments where the break point is. but there is nothing.
